# How to get current input language c++?

Tags: c++, input, system

How can I get the current input language in c++ systemwide. If I switch to another window and change input language there, how do I know that the language has changed and to which language?

Comment: That would depend on the system design and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Without knowing which operating system you're using, we can't tell you.  You'll need to call API functions for your OS, anyway - "language" isn't something that C++ itself has any concept of.

Comment: @benjymous C++ _does_ have a concept of locales, which subsumes language.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on OS, and in windows,try following codes:

```
char szBuf[25];
double thId;
HANDLE hCurrentKBLayout;

hCurrentKBLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
memset(szBuf, 0x00, 25);

ImmGetDescription(hCurrentKBLayout, szBuf, 50);
if(String(szBuf).Length()==0)
    strcpy(szBuf,"系统默认");
ShowMessage("current input language is:" + String(szBuf));
```

Comment: What does the keyboard layout have to do with the language the person is using?

Answer (score 1):

Officially, the locale `""` is supposed to correspond to an
implementation defined locale, which typically should correspond
to what the user wants his language to be.  Whether this works
in practice depends a lot on the implementation;
`std::locale().name()` seems to always return `"C"` on my
Windows machine (even though I'm *not* running a US version of
Windows).

More generally, there may not be a single "language".  Input,
for example, is, at the system level, generally language
neutral; the key factors are how the keyboard is set (but
I've often entered French or German from a US keyboard), and
once the characters are in your program, how you interpret them
(and presumably, what you want to know is how to interpret them,
according to what conventions).  If you want to know the
conventions other programs, or the OS use, you'll have to find
some OS specific means; it is a sort of standard that
environment variables like `LANG`, `LC_CTYPE`, etc. contain this
information, but how the different conventions are encoded
varies (although I think recent versions of Windows also support
the Posix standard forms), and OS's other than Unix often use
other means as well, so you'll need something OS specific here.